# Is there a sort of "conditional return"

Tags: php, function, return, conditional-statements

I'm writing a function that calls other functions until one of them returns a "not false" value. This value should be returned by the main function. 
What is the shortest manner of rewriting this function so it doesn't call the other functions twice, and - if possible - avoiding using an extra variable?

```php
function doSomething(){
    if (tryA()) return tryA();
    if (tryB()) return tryB();
    if (tryC()) return tryC();
    return screwIt();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply set a var in the if test and use it in the body of the if, as the returned value

```
function doSomething(){
    if ($ret = tryA()) return $ret;
    if ($ret = tryB()) return $ret;
    if ($ret = tryC()) return $ret;
    return screwIt();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
return tryA() ?: (tryB() ?: (tryC() ?: screwIt()));
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MvlcE)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```php
function doSomething() {
  if ($tryA = tryA()) return $tryA;
  if ($tryB = tryB()) return $tryB;
  if ($tryC = tryC()) return $tryC;
  return screwIt();
}
```

Comment: You are 2 minutes late compared to RiggsFolly :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a bunch of functions to call, you can store their name in a string array, and loop that array to avoid code duplication

```
function doSomething()
{
  $functions = array("tryA", "tryB", "tryC", "tryD", "tryE", "tryF");

  //                  v------------v----- This stops the loop on first non-falsy value found
  for ($i = $ret = 0; !(bool)$ret && $i < count($functions); $i++)
  {
      $ret = $functions[$i]();
  }

  return $ret ?: screwIt();
}
```

Note that `(bool)$ret` will be false if `$ret` =

```
0
""
"0"
false
null
[]
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I could see situations where the list of functions would work well.

Answer (score 1):

If you interested in logical values only, you can simply enumerate them via logical OR operator:

```php
return tryA() || tryB() || tryC() || screwIt();
```

The functions will be called from left to right until the non-empty value. The result will be casted to `false` or `true`.

If the exact value makes sense, use simplified form of "ternary" operator. Like this:

```php
return tryA() ?: tryB() ?: tryC() ?: screwIt();
```

it will call tryB() only when tryA() can be interpreted as `false` (i.e. 0, null, '', '0' or []), and so on and so forth.